# When I click the button it's not calling the function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

function calc() {

 var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
 var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
 var db1 = document.getElementById("db1").value;
 var db2 = document.getElementById("db2").value;
 var truckno = document.getElementById("truckno").value;

 var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
 rate = parseFloat(rate);

 var rate14 = document.getElementById("14rate").value;
 rate14 = parseFloat(rate14);

 var rate19 = document.getElementById("19rate").value;
 rate19 = parseFloat(rate19);

 var kms = document.getElementById("kms").value;
 kms = parseFloat(kms);

 var kme = document.getElementById("kme").value;
 kme = parseFloat(kme);

 var pricens14 = document.getElementById("14nsprice").value;
 pricens14 = parseFloat(pricens14);

 var prices14 = document.getElementById("14sprice").value;
 prices14 = parseFloat(prices14);

 var price19 = document.getElementById("19price").value;
 price19 = parseFloat(price19);

 var a1 = document.getElementById("a1").value;
 a1 = parseFloat(a1);

 var b1 = document.getElementById("b1").value;
 b1 = parseFloat(b1);

 var c1 = document.getElementById("c1").value;
 c1 = parseFloat(c1);

 var a2 = document.getElementById("a2").value;
 a2 = parseFloat(a2);

 var b2 = document.getElementById("b2").value;
 b2 = parseFloat(b2);

 var c2 = document.getElementById("c2").value;
 c2 = parseFloat(c2);


 var total_cyl_loaded = a1 + b1 + c1;
 total_cyl_loaded = parseFloat(total_cyl_loaded);

 var total_cyl_returned = a2 + b2 + c2;
 total_cyl_returned = parseFloat(total_cyl_returned);

 var ns14_diff = a1 - a2;
 ns14_diff = parseFloat(ns14_diff);

 var sold_out_14 = ns14_diff * rate14;
 sold_out_14 = parseFloat(sold_out_14);

 var total_cyl_loaded = a1 + b1 + c1;
 total_cyl_loaded = parseFloat(total_cyl_loaded);

 var total_cyl_returned = a2 + b2 + c2;
 total_cyl_returned = parseFloat(total_cyl_returned);

 var ns14_diff = a1 - a2;
 ns14_diff = parseFloat(ns14_diff);

 var n19_diff = c1 - c2;
 ns19_diff = parseFloat(ns19_diff);

 var sold_out_14 = ns14_diff * rate14;
 sold_out_14 = parseFloat(sold_out_14);

 var sold_out_19 = n19_diff * rate19;
 sold_out_19 = parseFloat(sold_out_19);


 var price_14ns_returned = a1 * pricens14;
 price_14ns_returned = parseFloat(price_14ns_returned);

 var price_14s_returned = a2 * prices14;
 price_14s_returned = parseFloat(price_14s_returned);

 var price_19_returned = a * price19;
 price_19_returned = parseFloat(price_19_returned);

 var run_km = kme - kms;
 run_km = parseFloat(run_km);

 var truck_km_rate = run_km * rate;
 truck_km_rate = parseFloat(truck_km_rate);

 var total_cash_returned = price_14ns_returned + price_14s_returned + price_19_returned + sold_out_14 + sold_out_19 + truck_km_rate;

}
</script>
```

```
<input type="button" id="bbtn" name ="btn" onclick="calc();" value="Calculate">
```

Comment: Where is the html for this? Where is the `button` and can you format the source code for better reading, thank you.

Comment: What about using an object to save your numbers? But yes, show the button that calls `calc()`. Your js code seems finnicky, but correct.

Comment: <input type="button" id="bbtn" name ="btn" onclick="calc();" value="Calculate">

Comment: What is the error in your console ?

Comment: can't find variable s19_diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment the error lies here:

```
var n19_diff = c1 - c2;
ns19_diff = parseFloat(ns19_diff);
```

You declare your variable as `n19_diff` but try to `parseFloat` a variable named `ns19_diff` - which doesn't exist - Notice the missing `s` in your variable declaration